# Get nil value from sql in Go

Tags: mysql, go, query-builder

let say I have a struct **Profile** and sql table **profiles**.

```
type Profile struct {
    ID        int       `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    FirstName string    `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string    `json:"last_name"`
    Age       int       `json:"age"`
}
```

And, I get a record from **profiles** table, assign into the Profile struct.

These fields are **allow null**, so that I used **sql.NullString**, **sql.NullInt64**, **pq.NullTime** to check valid value before assign to struct.

```
// ... DB.Query(...)
// ... rows.Next()
// ... rows.Scan()
// ...
if firstName.Valid {
    p.FirstName = firstName.String
}
if lastName.Valid {
    p.LastName = lastName.String
}
if age.Valid {
    p.Age = age.Int64
}
// ...
```

If I have more than 10 tables, each tables has more than 30 columns, I have to check all variables again and again.
That make ugly code, someone have any suggestion to make it pretty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be checking like that at all. The nullable types are intended for use directly in structs:

```
type Profile struct {
    ID        sql.NullInt64  `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    FirstName sql.NullString `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  sql.NullString `json:"last_name"`
    Age       sql.NullInt64  `json:"age"`
}
```

Then access the values using, for example, `product.FirstName.String()`.  There is no reason for checking `product.FirstName.Valid` except where you actually care about the distinction between `nil` and an empty value (in the examples in your question, you clearly don't care about this distinction).

An alternative, which may be more suitable in some situations, is to just use a pointer:

```
type Profile struct {
    ID        *int      `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at"`
    FirstName *string   `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  *string   `json:"last_name"`
    Age       *int      `json:"age"`
}
```

Of course then any code that uses these variables must dereference them, and check for `nil`, so this may not always be the most desirable, depending on how you use the values.

A third option, if you never care about the distinction between a `NULL` value and and empty value, is to create your own type which treats these the same.  Example:

```
type myString string

func (s *myString) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if src == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if value, ok := src.(string); ok {
        *s = value
        return nil
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("Unsupported type for myString: %T", src)
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of the first solution is that it exposes anything that consumes your model to the `sql` package and its semantics.

Comment: hi Flimzy, sorry about the delay in response, good solutions, but it's make me change many lines of code, I searched around and finally, I decided to use [queries.Bind](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/blob/master/queries/reflect.go#L85) from `sqlboiler`, thanks anyway